# Getting values from a JSON object

Tags: android, json, api

I have received this output here:

```
{
   "hi:{
      "id":35445129,
      "name":"Hi",
      "profileIconId":28,
      "revisionDate":1428718587000,
      "summonerLevel":30
   }
}
```

from the Riot Games api.

I tried to use this code here:

```
    GetRequest gr = Unirest.get("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/
    summoner/by-name/hi?api_key={this is my key that I won't put in}");

    HttpResponse<JsonNode> node =  gr.asJson();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(node.getBody());
    System.out.println(obj.getJSONObject(name).getInt("id"));
```

to try to print out the value for the id, but I get this exception when I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["hi"] not found.
at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:459)
at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:558)
at thing.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

Anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Apparently your "Hi" key doesn't have any value. Also, your JSON seems to be in a wrong format. Use [this website](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) for further validation.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong thats why exception is coming. Istead of {

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong. Look at what your exception tells you:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["hi"] not found.
```

It is because you forgot the closing double quote on `hi`.

This is what you have:

```
{
   "hi:{
      "id":35445129,
      "name":"Hi",
      "profileIconId":28,
      "revisionDate":1428718587000,
      "summonerLevel":30
   }
}
```

But it should be:

```
{
   "hi":{
      "id":35445129,
      "name":"Hi",
      "profileIconId":28,
      "revisionDate":1428718587000,
      "summonerLevel":30
   }
}
```